# WordPress Ajax Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, wordpress

I'm having a WordPress template file from where I'm getting the user_id and response_id and passing those to javascript written in same file at bottom. All of the ids are passing properly but only for the url I'm getting error. How can I solve this issue? When I am testing it on local environment it works fine but when I upload it on live server `Uncaught ReferenceError: url is not defined` and here is the javascript code:

```
<script>
                $(document).ready(function() {

                    $('#vote-' + <?php echo $response->id; ?>).on('click', function() {
                        var response_id = "<?php echo $response->id; ?>";
                        var user_id = "<?php echo get_current_user_id(); ?>";

                        $.ajax({
                            url: "<?php echo esc_url(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/Votes.php'); ?>",
                            method: "post",
                            data: {
                                response_id: response_id,
                                user_id: user_id
                            },
                            beforeSend: function() {

                            },
                            success: function(response) {
                                alert('Thanks for your response!');
                                //location.reload(true);
                            },
                            error: function(jqXHR, status, err) {
                                var msg = '';
                                console.log(url);
                                if (jqXHR.status === 0) {
                                    msg = 'Not connect.\n Verify Network.';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status == 404) {
                                    msg = 'Requested page not found. [404]';
                                } else if (jqXHR.status == 500) {
                                    msg = 'Internal Server Error [500].';
                                } else if (exception === 'parsererror') {
                                    msg = 'Requested JSON parse failed.';
                                } else if (exception === 'timeout') {
                                    msg = 'Time out error.';
                                } else if (exception === 'abort') {
                                    msg = 'Ajax request aborted.';
                                } else {
                                    msg = 'Uncaught Error.\n' + jqXHR.responseText;
                                }
                                alert(msg);
                                alert('Please try again to cast your vote');
                                // window.location.href = '/plan';
                                // $("#claimajaxresponse1").html(jqXHR.status);
                                console.log(jqXHR.status);
                                return false;

                            }
                        });
                    });
                });
                </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

the url you are consoling is not a variable, remove it or define first.

Answer (score 0):

If you comment out or remove the following line of code, this specific issue will be solved:
`console.log(url)`